# Countdown script that don't work on safari

Tags: javascript, safari, countdowntimer

I have that script and it work very well but got some problem with safari and firefox.
The problem is NaN!

[image]

Should be:

[image]

```
var traddate;

function cdtime(container, targetdate, traduzione){
    if (!document.getElementById || !document.getElementById(container)) return
    this.container=document.getElementById(container)
    this.currentTime=new Date()
    this.targetdate=new Date(targetdate)
    this.timesup=false
    this.updateTime()
    traddate=traduzione
}

cdtime.prototype.updateTime=function(){
var thisobj=this
this.currentTime.setSeconds(this.currentTime.getSeconds()+1)
setTimeout(function(){thisobj.updateTime()}, 1000) //Aggiorna ogni secondo
}

cdtime.prototype.displaycountdown=function(baseunit, functionref){
    this.baseunit=baseunit
    this.formatresults=functionref
    this.showresults()
}

cdtime.prototype.showresults=function(){
var thisobj=this
```

This section should be store the current time.

```
var timediff=(this.targetdate-this.currentTime)/1000 //Differenza tra la data desiderata e quella corrente, in secondi
if (timediff<0){ 
this.timesup=true
this.container.innerHTML=this.formatresults()
return
}
var oneMinute=60 //minuti in secondi
var oneHour=60*60 //ore in secondi
var oneDay=60*60*24 //giorni in secondi
var dayfield=Math.floor(timediff/oneDay)
var hourfield=Math.floor((timediff-dayfield*oneDay)/oneHour)
var minutefield=Math.floor((timediff-dayfield*oneDay-hourfield*oneHour)/oneMinute)
var secondfield=Math.floor((timediff-dayfield*oneDay-hourfield*oneHour-minutefield*oneMinute))
if (this.baseunit=="hours"){ 
hourfield=dayfield*24+hourfield
dayfield="n/a"
}
else if (this.baseunit=="minutes"){ 
minutefield=dayfield*24*60+hourfield*60+minutefield
dayfield=hourfield="n/a"
}
else if (this.baseunit=="seconds"){ 
var secondfield=timediff
dayfield=hourfield=minutefield="n/a"
}
this.container.innerHTML=this.formatresults(dayfield, hourfield, minutefield, secondfield)
setTimeout(function(){thisobj.showresults()}, 1000) //Aggiorna ogni secondo
}
```

And there is the code for result print. The error should be in this section, I think.

```
function formatresults(){
    if (this.timesup==false){//Se la data non è stata ancora raggiunta
        var displaystring=arguments[0]+" "+traddate+" "+arguments[1]+":"+arguments[2]+":"+arguments[3]
    } else { //se la data è stata raggiunta
        var displaystring="Data raggiunta"
    }
    return displaystring
}
```

Solutions?
It seem work only on chrome.

Comment: What is the value for `targetdate`?

Comment: If targetdate is in an invalid format the date object will be invalid and subtracting it from a valid date will result in NaN.

Comment: Targetdate is a date in SQL database of the end of countdown.
Format is unixtime and it's like this: 1451520000
I need to convert it?